# How to get button ID from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I try to using popovers from [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/popovers/).

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    popoverOpen: false
  };
}

toggle = () => {
  this.setState({popoverOpen: !this.state.popoverOpen})
};

<div>
  <Button id="Popover1" type="button">
    Launch Popover
  </Button>
  <Popover placement="bottom" isOpen={this.state.popoverOpen} target="Popover1" toggle={this.toggle}>
    <PopoverHeader>Popover Title</PopoverHeader>
    <PopoverBody>Hello there :)</PopoverBody>
  </Popover>
</div>
```

The code above already works.

But, for now I want to separate the button on another component.

So, any example how to do that..?

Is it possible to taking the button ID from another component..?
Or, should I setState from another component..?
if so, please give an example or source to learn that.

Comment: Have you tried passing the id trough component props?

Answer (score 1):

I think this task can be solved with [React state lifting](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

The idea is to create Button component as you wish and pass to it`toggle` function, so Button component will call it on each call. Also you may pass `this.state.popoverOpen` so Button component will know if popover currently open. Your min component will have the same state, but your Button component will have parent's state as props.

Here is example (this code is not tested! Use it as hint only!)

```
// ButtonComponent.js
// import React and other nesessary things
export default class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render () {
        return <Button id={this.porps.ButtonID} type="button" onClick={this.props.toggle}>
            Launch Popover
        </Button>
    }
}

// mainComponent.js
import ButtonComponent from './ButtonComponent.js'

export default MainComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            popoverOpen: false
        };
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState({popoverOpen: !this.state.popoverOpen})
    };

    render () {
        return <div>
            <ButtonComponent toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)} ButtonID={"Popover1"}/>
            <Popover placement="bottom" isOpen={this.state.popoverOpen} target="Popover1" toggle={this.toggle}>
                <PopoverHeader>Popover Title</PopoverHeader>
                <PopoverBody>Hello there :)</PopoverBody>
            </Popover>
        </div>
    }
}
```